# Preventing ios from rounding corners in safari not working. css

Tags: css

I have tried the codes below to prevent safari on mobile devices from rounding corners but they are not working. Can someone help me A Little.

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
-webkit-border-radius:0px;
 border-radius:0px;
```

Comment: They are a input text field and input buttons inside a div element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use those css rules within an appropriate css selector.

So to remove Safari's default styles from inputs and buttons use this:

```
input, button {
    -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

Comment: That did not work either can I have some more detailed information. Like since they are in a div element should I specify the path in the div?

Comment: hmm just to test try using `* { -webkit-appearance:none; }` and if it still doesn't work `* { -webkit-appearance:none !important; }`

Comment: ...also use 'inspect element' to see if the css rule is being overidden (crossed out)

Comment: I got it to work by specifying it in the div then all of the input elements in it. But the border of the text field goes outside the border on ios but not pc any reason why.

Comment: no it works fine its just the text field goes outside the div.

Comment: hmm that sounds like a different question altogether